# How to get the data for exact urls in analytics segments?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to compare my Google Analytics data to the traffic data from my server access log.

There is a big difference between the two data sets. Google analytics data is showing more traffic.

The condition I am using is:

[image: analytics conditions]

Does this condition include the exact urls or ones with parameters as well? If it's not exact url match, how can I filter it with exact urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting it to 'Exactly matches' this it will filter out any parameters.

By the way: having GA show more data than the server logs seems odd.

- Are you sure you're looking at users in GA and not sessions?
- Did you filter out as many bots and sessions as possible?

Comment: I was using that condition already but cheers for confirmation. It is rather odd. I'll probably need to check our server logs. I was looking at pageviews, not users. Should it be users instead? Also, exactly matches includes requests with parameters (like `?url_campaign=mycampa` ).